# Correct interpretation of estimates in poisson regression output

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression, poisson-process

I am learning to use and validate the Poisson regression model and interpret the results. I am using some data on grassland plant diversity in response to fertilizer and light. The experimental design is fully crossed; there were a total of32 plots, 8 received fertilizer and light(F+L+), 8 received fertilizer and no light (F+L-), 8 received no fertilizer and light (F-L+), and 8 received no fertilizer and no light(F-L-). The number of species was counted in each plot. In these grassland systems, there is typically a loss of species diversity in response to fertilization, which may be due to light competition. My goal is to estimate whether the loss of species can be prevented by restoring light to these areas.

Here is an example of the data:

```r
structure(list(Fertilizer = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("F-", "F+"
), class = "factor"), Light = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("L-", 
"L+"), class = "factor"), FL = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("F-L-", 
"F-L+", "F+L-", "F+L+"), class = "factor"), LF = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("L-F-", 
"L-F+", "L+F-", "L+F+"), class = "factor"), Diversity = c(6L, 
7L, 10L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 
4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -32L))
```

I fit a Poisson distribution model as follows:

`PlantMod <- glm(Diversity~FL, data = plants, family = poisson (link = log))`

Which gives the following output:

```
> summary(PlantMod)

Call:
glm(formula = Diversity ~ FL, family = poisson(link = log), data = plants)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.92920  -0.24454   0.04186   0.38080   0.91640  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.9981     0.1302  15.348   <2e-16 ***
FLF-L+        0.1851     0.1762   1.051   0.2933    
FLF+L-       -0.4940     0.2115  -2.336   0.0195 *  
FLF+L+        0.1710     0.1767   0.967   0.3334    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 21.2770  on 31  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  6.6221  on 28  degrees of freedom
AIC: 136.61

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

I want to make sure I am interpreting the estimate results correctly, I haven't been able to find good examples using crossed designs like this. Here are a few specific questions I have:

- R chose (F-L-) as the baseline/reference group and gave an estimate of 1.9981. Is the exponential of this `exp(1.9981)` interpreted as the average effect on Y (`Diversity`), when the other estimators are at X=0? Does it matter which group is used as a baseline (is it related to the question you are trying to answer)?
- From what I understand, the slopes can be interpreted as the average effect of the respective estimator on the fitted values for diversity (which incorporates all Y-values, or Diversity values, across all treatment groups). For example the estimated slope for the F-L+ group is 0.1851; since this is reported on the link scale, you could calculate `1-exp(0.1851)=-0.203`, and conclude that the model would predict a 20.3% decrease in diversity in F-L+ plots when compared to F-L- plots?
- I am not sure how to interpret the p-values in this case. Only (F-L-) and (F+L-) had significant p-values. Is this saying that the average of the (F-L+) and (F+L+) groups (which had the insignificant p-values) are not significantly different in diversity than the (F-L-) group, or that those groups didn't have a significant effect on the outcome of the actual response (Y or Diversity)?
- advice on how to validate this model (if I used the best link function, and when I might consider switching to a different distribution, such as quasi-Poisson or whatever else) would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficients basically tell you what is the response value to expect for each group, using one of them as reference. So in your design, it's essentially something close to the group mean.

You can first check the mean diversity per group:

```
with(plants,tapply(Diversity,FL,mean))
 F-L-  F-L+  F+L-  F+L+ 
7.375 8.875 4.500 8.750
```

And in log space:

```
log(with(plants,tapply(Diversity,FL,mean)))
    F-L-     F-L+     F+L-     F+L+ 
1.998096 2.183238 1.504077 2.169054
```

And you can see, the first intercept is roughly log (mean of F-L-) and coefficient for FLF-L+ is roughly 2.183238 - 1.998096 = 0.185142.

In your design, there is no slope to speak of. The coefficients tells you something like a log fold change over the reference group, for example, the coefficient of F-L+ is 0.185142, meaning you expect exp(0.185142) =  1.203389 fold over F-L-.

As for your remaining question, some groups might not show a difference over reference, you can always check later with posthoc, using `multcomp` package.

you should check whether it follows a poisson and in your case, it is actually underdispersed:

```
fit_q = glm(Diversity~FL, data = plants, family = quasipoisson)
summary(fit_q)

Call:
glm(formula = Diversity ~ FL, family = quasipoisson, data = plants)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.92920  -0.24454   0.04186   0.38080   0.91640  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.99810    0.06330  31.564  < 2e-16 ***
FLF-L+       0.18514    0.08566   2.161   0.0394 *  
FLF+L-      -0.49402    0.10283  -4.804 4.74e-05 ***
FLF+L+       0.17096    0.08593   1.989   0.0565 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasipoisson family taken to be 0.2364279)
```

Are you only providing a selected subset of the data? It's very rare to see underdispersion unless there is some underlying reason for it.

Comment: No actually that was the full data set